# Malloc vs static array in C

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic, static, malloc

It is often said to use malloc when size is known at run time we could also write

```
int x;
scanf("%d",&x);
char arr[x];
```

so why use malloc when we can declare array on the fly.

Comment: @YassineHoussni ugh, huuge assertions. The "it's faster" statement is even wrong. Dynamic memory allocation is one of the slowest "primitive" operations. Usually, declaring a VLA makes memory available almost instantly (it's only the stack pointer that needs to be added/subtracted a certain number), unlike `malloc()` which involves searching through a free store (potentially and often implemented using complex data structures with large constant factors).

Comment: Someone should also remember that while, a `malloc()` requires `free()` VLA's don't, and that is very important specially for large arrays.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Writing `char arr[x];` will allocate the memory on the stack.

The size of the stack is typically limited to around 1MB. You'll get runtime errors if you exceed this pre-defined amount. Some compilers will allow you to change the stack size, but you'll still hit a limit eventually of many orders of magnitude than you can get with `malloc`.

Comment: so the size of memory needed and the scope of the data decides when to use static or dynamic.Is there any other reason?

Comment: I don't think the stack is typically so small, and all of the answers lack any advice on using `free()` which in the case of using `malloc()` just because the stack doesn't fit the data for it's size, is really really important.

Comment: @iharob: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686774%28v=vs.85%29.aspx 1 MB by default on Windows (requested size stored in the executable), 8 MB by default on my Linux 64 bit machine (as per `ulimit -s`). I wouldn't try to load an image or anything biggish on it (especially since stack overflows are particularly nasty on Windows, the process just disappears).

Comment: @MatteoItalia I have a solution, don't load the data on the stack if you know it's going to be a lot of data, and also don't use windows. But if your data is known not to exceed the stack size, you should avoid using `malloc()`, both, for performance reasons and for simplicity. An image > 8MB is quite a large image, isn't it? it's not so commom except in games and image editing/viewing software perhaps.

Comment: @iharob: that's exactly the point; stack allocation is fine for buffers on the small side (typically a few KBs), but you have to be careful when working with data coming from outside. In these cases, even without VLAs, it's customary to have a small stack-allocated buffer with a fallback to `malloc` when stuff gets big.

Comment: @iharob: an 8 MB image is nothing special, take a 3 megapixels RGB image and you are already there.

Answer (score 2):

`VLA` [Variable length array] is a concept present in `C99` onwards.

`malloc()` originates much before that.

Also, `malloc()` and family allocates memory from heap. It does not use the *comparatively limited* stack space.

OTOH, `gcc` allocates space for `VLA`s in the stack itself.